# Accessing a dict, replacing items in a user input with the information from the dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, input

Im trying to access a dict ive created called Brands.
I am then trying to replace information from a user input with information from the dict. I am struggiling to print out and replace text of the user input. Currently the only thing I can get it to do is print out all of the table content, with words inserted which unfortunately doesnt help very much.

```
BRANDS = {
  'Velcro': 'hook and loop fastener',
  'Kleenex': 'tissues',
  'Hoover': 'vacuum',
  'Bandaid': 'sticking plaster',
  'Thermos': 'vacuum flask',
  'Dumpster': 'garbage bin',
  'Rollerblade': 'inline skate',
  'Asprin': 'acetylsalicylic acid'
}


userinput = input("Sentence: ")
print('a', userinput, 'is', BRANDS[userinput])
```

**This is an example that my code must do.**

```
Sentence: I bought some Velcro shoes.

Result >>> I bought some hook and loop fastener shoes.
```

Comment: That's not a list its a dictionary. To understand how they work take a look at [these tutorials](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files) and the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Thanks, only just learning dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to cycle through your dictionary and perform `str.replace` repeatedly:

```
def replacer(x, d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        x = x.replace(k, v)
    return x

userinput = input("Sentence: ")
print(replacer(userinput, BRANDS))
```

Example:

```
Sentence: I bought some Velcro shoes.
I bought some hook and loop fastener shoes.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really apprieciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for key in BRANDS:
    userinput = userinput.replace(key, BRANDS[key])

print(userinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
def repl(d,s):
    d={k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in s}
    return s.replace(next(iter(d)),next(iter(d.values())))
inp = input("Sentence: ")
print(repl(BRANDS,inp))
```

Example Output:

```
Sentence: I bought some Velcro shoes
I bought some hook and loop fastener shoes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.get()` with a list comprehension to iterate over the values of your user input (separated by space) and replace them with the values from your BRANDS dictionary. The `dict.get()` method will first check if a key of that particular value of `i` exists. If it does it will return the corresponding value from the BRANDS dict or else just keep the original value of `i`. You can then pass this list to `str.join()` to form the final string

```
print(' '.join(BRANDS.get(i,i) for i in userinput.split()))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does not require looping over all elements in your `dict`.

By using a regex, you can do the replacement in a single traversal instead of using `str.replace` for each element in `BRANDS`.

### Code

```
import re

BRANDS = ...

def replacer(sentence, replacements):
    pattern = '|'.join(replacements)
    repl = lambda m: replacements[m.group()]

    return re.sub(pattern, repl, sentence)

userinput = input("Sentence: ")

print(replacer(userinput, BRANDS))
```

### Example

```
Sentence: Kleenex and Hoover
tissues and vacuum
```