# Print Dictionary variables

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, replace

```
BRANDS = {
'Velcro': 'hook and loop fastener',
'Kleenex': 'tissues',
'Hoover': 'vacuum',
'Bandaid': 'sticking plaster',
'Thermos': 'vacuum flask',
'Dumpster': 'garbage bin',
'Rollerblade': 'inline skate',
'Aspirin': 'acetylsalicylic acid'
}
sentence = input (Sentence: )
```

I want it to print something like this:

```
Sentence: I bought some Velcro shoes.
I bought some hook and loop fastener shoes.
```

Comment: Didn't that assignment come out weeks ago? Are you doing a makeup?

Comment: `print(' '.join(BRANDS.get(i, i) for i in sentence.split()))`

Comment: You should take shoe brand as input and get the key from dict and make a sentence.

Comment: What no i am still doing it

Comment: Its about Grok if you didn't know Mad Physicist

Comment: It is  a little unclear what the core of yoru goal is (though guessing can help there). It is however very unclear what your problem is. How to make a HelloWorld in python? How to access one value in a dictionary, based on a key? How to find a key in a sentence? How to replace a word in a sentence with a string? Please show how much you achieved towards your goal and then ask a specific question about the detail which got you stuck. As it is, your question looks like "Please do my homework for me."

Comment: @AAdi What have you tried so far?

Comment: ' '.join(BRANDS.get(val,val) for val in sentence.split(' '))

Comment: @riyasyash Without brackets (`[` and `]`) would work too, that will be faster

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923190/accessing-a-dict-replacing-items-in-a-user-input-with-the-information-from-the/51923432#51923432

Comment: @U9-Forward cool thank you.

Comment: @riyasyash I am here to teach, happy that you could learn something, 

Comment: Thanks to anyone who has helped, and i appreciate it, but i get an error: Testing the third example in the question. Your submission did not produce the correct output. Your program output:

Sentence: Buy some Aspirin and Kleenex.
Buy some acetylsalicylic acid and Kleenex.
​
when it was meant to output:

Sentence: Buy some Aspirin and Kleenex.
Buy some acetylsalicylic acid and tissues.
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Burhan's idea, using this:

```
sentence = input('Sentence: ')
print(' '.join(BRANDS.get(i,i) for i in sentence.split()))
```

Also possible using for loop:

```
sentence = input('Sentence: ')
for i in sentence.split():
   sentence=sentence.replace(i,BRANDS.get(i,i))
print(sentence)
```

Comment: Are you aware of this? Your comment seems in line, your answer in contrast to the idea. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions